# How do i add a custom field to a devise registration in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, mass-assignment

I am trying to add one field to my registration page that uses devise.  I followed the instructions in the Devise document.  The new field is the "role" field.  I have already succesfully migrated it to the database.  I am now trying to make it so that the signup works.    Here is the new applicationcontroller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

    def devise_parameter_sanitizer
        if resource_class == User
          User::ParameterSanitizer.new(User, :user, params)
        else
          super # Use the default one
        end
    end
end
```

And here is the changed User model:

```
class User::ParameterSanitizer < Devise::ParameterSanitizer
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  def sign_up
    default_params.permit(:email, :role)
  end
end
```

Once I added these two files, the server cannot even load.  How do I successfully add the role field?

EDIT

Here is my routes.rb file

```
devise_for :users
root 'static_pages#home'
get 'student' => 'static_pages#index'
```

Comment: did you generate devise views?

Comment: Yes, but I added the form field to the form:  <%= f.input :role %>

Comment: can you show your routes.rb and the devise extended controller?

Comment: What do you mean devise extended controller?  I will add my routes.rb file

Comment: I added my routes.rb file above

Comment: please go through [this railscast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise) for more details.  you need to create a custom devise controller and generate views for any sort of customization.

Comment: The railscast did not answer my question.  It was in Rails 3 so attar_accessible is deprecated.  Also, it did not mention any custom controller.

Comment: By the way, thanks for your help rb512.

Comment: attr_accessor has been deprecated in rails 4 and not attr_accessible

Comment: Either way, I don't think either of those are supposed to be used for this.

Comment: without attr_accessible, rails won't allow you to modify a field from your forms.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use this:  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use following approach to add custom field in devise user table.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) } # The :firstname and :lastname are my custom fields.
  end

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

Comment: Thanks!  That works, but the devise documentation says that this is the "lazy" way to do it.  Do you know why?  Is this good enough to use for production?

Comment: I didn't know why this is lazy way but I think you can use it on production server.

Comment: One more thing i have read the devise doc then i have found that you are using the code which is to be use only if you have more than one devise model.