# Rails devise ParameterSanitizer for loging using custom field (auth_key)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I have tried Devise gem with its default configuration , where users can login with there email address ,and its worked prefect.
Iin my case i need no use a registration_number (other that a email address) to users to logged in but when i try to sign_up a new user using registration_number its only insert password to the database this is the query i took from log file

```
 User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`registration_number` = BINARY '114150C' LIMIT 1
  SQL (49.6ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`encrypted_password`) VALUES ('$2a$10$Fp3HCYszDjEDkl0DHCBCLuI9RttOaAQE2pi2xcTSkaMU9QNbW/8D6')
```

so what i did was
(as instructed in here and some other stack sites)
1. run a migration to change the name of users email column to registration_number
2. change config/initializers/devise.rb accordingly (replace :email with :registration_number)
3. create user_sanitizer.rb in the lib directory as mentioned in here and
put this code into it

```
class User::ParameterSanitizer &lt; Devise::ParameterSanitizer
    private
    def account_update
        default_params.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
    end
end
```

4. add before filter to ApplicationController.rb according to the the lazy way™ mentioned in here
   (meanwhile i have change views and controllers accordingly )
   but still , when i try to sign_up a new user its only inserting password to the database registration_number column not get inserted  and i'm not getting any errors as-well

tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371013/how-do-i-add-a-custom-field-to-a-devise-registration-in-rails-4) as-well

Comment: Actually, it appears that you've kind of posted a mixed up thing of question and answer. That isn't what this site is for. If you want to share something, it needs to conform to the Q&A format of the site.

Comment: @meagar thanks for the advice , i have deleted that comment and post it as a answer, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i have solved it,
only thing i have to do is comment this line in user.rb model

## attr_accessor :registration_number